# SQL Server Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have a pending project that may or may not be a good candidate for leveraging SQL Server Analysis Services.  The project is based around business metric calculations.

Does anyone have some good recommended reading for a crash course in SQL Server Analysis Services that'll let me catch up to speed on what the capabilities and uses are to help me decide if it is worth digging in to further?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been reading [Delivering Business Intelligence with Microsoft SQL Server 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071549447) by Brian Larson and think this is the best book for a beginner on the subject.  He is a good writer and has an easy style.  His focus is on the overview and allowing you to understand SSAS basics.  I'm not sure a seasoned pro would get much out of it, but for me it was perfect.  I've also got the [Wrox Professional book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470247983), which has far more detail but is a less enjoyable read.

Comment: Thanks. Found the 2005 version on Safari Online.  Looks exactly like what I need.

Comment: If you are a visual learner, you might also want to check out the free video series by Craig Utley at http://www.learnmicrosoftbi.com/  The quality is high and on par with most training programs that you would pay for.  You have to register (free) but then you can download all the videos.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8730566/606101) is the answer for a similar question on stackoverflow, and has some useful links for a SSAS beginner. However some links for msdev.com are not working as given in th eanser but rest are good.